# React component's state using the useState hook resets unexpectedly in between child component updates

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a simple React component which maintains an array of people in state using the `useState` hook. The component allows addition of new people with a simple child form component.  It is not functioning as expected as the `people` state array seems to be resetting/reverting to its initial value between additions from the child form.

The structure of the components is below:

### Parent Component

The main parent component looks like the below. It stores an array, `people` in state. It also passes an `onPersonSaved` function to the `PersonEditor` component.  `onPersonSaved` is called when the editor's save button is clicked (more on this later) and simply adds (without mutating) the new person to the `people` array

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [people, setPeople] = useState( [
    { id: 1, firstName: "John", lastName: "Smith" },
    { id: 2, firstName: "Peter", lastName: "Jones" },
    { id: 3, firstName: "Sally", lastName: "Wilson" },
  ]);

  const onPersonSaved = (person) => {
      setPeople([...people, person]);
    }

  const addNew = () => {
    onPersonSaved({ id: 4, title: "Jane", url: "Johnson" });
  };


  return (
    <div>
      <Button type="button" onClick={addNew} content="Add Jane" />
      <PersonEditor
        onSubmit={onPersonSaved}
        person={people[0]}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

### Child Form

The child form is defined below.  It is reasoably simple and accepts a person to edit via it's `person` prop. This is stored in state and is updated using `useEffect` if the `person` prop changes.

It also uses a custom hook `useForm` to maintain the field states and trigger the `onPersonSaved` callback. For info, `Button`, and `Input` are semantic-ui-react components.

```
const PERSON_INITIALVALUE = {
  id: null,
  firstName: "",
  lastName: ""
}

const PersonEditor = (props) => {
  const [person, setLink] = useState(PERSON_INITIALVALUE);

  const personForm = useForm(person, {
    submit: (values) => {
      if (props.onSubmit) {
        props.onSubmit(values);
        setLink(PERSON_INITIALVALUE);
      }
    },
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.person) {
      setLink({ ...props.person });
    }
  }, [props.person]);


  return (
    <Fragment>
          <Input
            type="text"
            name="firstName"
            value={personForm.values.firstName}
            onChange={(e, data) => personForm.setField("firstName", data.value)}
          />
          <Input
            type="text"
            name="lastName"
            value={personForm.values.lastName}
            onChange={(e, data) => personForm.setField("lastName", data.value)}
          />
          <Button
            type="button"
            primary
            content="Save Person"
            onClick={personForm.submit}
          />
        </Fragment>
  );
};
```

### The useForm Hook

This is a custom hook which provides very simple form handling functionality - namely field management and a submit method. It accepts a set of initial values (in this case a person object) and an options object, which is this case is just the `submit` property/function.

```
const useForm = (initialValues, opts) => {

  const [options] = useState(opts);
  const [values, setValues] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    if (initialValues) {
      setValues({ ...initialValues });
    }
  }, [initialValues]);

  const setField = (field, value) => {
    setValues({ ...values, [field]: value });
  };

  const submit = () => {
    options.submit(values);
  };


  return {
    setField,
    values,
    submit,
  };
};

export default useForm;
```

### The Problem

When I add a new person through the form, it appends it to the array *seemingly* without problem. However, when I add another person the person is added, but before this happens, the `people` array seems to have reverted/reset to the original initial value.

So, on first addition, the array has the original three people plus the new person added through the editor. The array is therefore `[John, Peter, Sally, FIRST NEW PERSON]` On second addition, the array has the original three people but has not retained the first person, but has added the second person.  The array looks like  `[John, Peter, Sally, SECOND NEW PERSON]`

If I call the `onPersonSaved` function directly from the parent component by clicking on the `Add Jane` button, I can add Jane as many times as I like and the `people` state array behaves as expected.

When using the form and custom hook, why does the state not maintain and why does it reset to its initial value?

Comment: can you please give code sandbox link

Comment: try changing `options.submit(values);` to `opts.submit(values);`

Comment: Also take a look at the key-value pairs of object inside `addNew` function and the objects in `people` array in `Parent` component. Here's a [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-maedyt?file=Parent.js) in which i have removed unnecessary code

Comment: @Yousaf  Thanks for the help!  For the first comment, options.submit is correct, opts was my typo when posting the code.  I've got my code working now.  It seems that when the `submit` function is called via the `useForm` hook (i..e passed via the `useForm` `options` object), it doesn't work and state is 'reset'.  When the `submit` function is placed in the child editor component rather than the `useForm` hook, everything works as it should.  Why is this?